# Share Internet connection in windows using c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

In my office, There is one PC on which internet connection is enable and rest of the PC's are connected to that computer in LAN. Is there any way, I can access internet connection to other PC's as well using C#?

Comment: So, do you have two NICs (Ethernet ports) on the PC which has the network connection? Are you using Windows, Linux or OSX? And do you have a network switch?

Comment: Only one NIC. PC is running on Windows 7. I want to develop an application or WCF service which can help to share the internet connection on other PC's as well.

Comment: Ok, but the biggest problem is that you would need a second nic for the LAN (since the first one is connected to internet).

Comment: Please see the link: [Windows 7 share network connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7) It's a built in feature of Windows 7, so why do you want to build a new application for that?